# angular-dragula - always drag to the list end

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular-dragula

I need some help.

I am using the angular-dragula.js and needed to set up that when you drag any object to another list, it goes to the end. Even if I drop anywhere he goes to the end of the list.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do this? Already researched in various locations and without any success.

this is an **example**, but that only works clicking on the item needed to do work when dragged.

**jsFiddle Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vf6dnwxj/11/)

```
drake = dragula([left1, right1]);
drake.on('drop', function(el, target, source, sibling){

});
var leftList = document.querySelector('#left1');
var rightList = document.querySelector('#right1');
var list = document.querySelectorAll('#right1 li, #left1 li');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            drake.start(this);
        if (this.parentNode.id == 'right1') {
        leftList.appendChild(this);
      } else {
        rightList.appendChild(this);
      }
      drake.end();
  });
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you used. If the code is too big to post, try to reduce it to a minimal example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this is an example, but that only works clicking on the item needed to do work when dragged.
    http://jsfiddle.net/vf6dnwxj/11/

Comment: I just [answered this for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337061/dragula-how-to-always-move-an-item-to-end-of-list#answer-59340712) before seeing this one. Three years late to the game, but here is a working example anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/t6pbf8j5/